# why the n power of (-1)^n in this power series stay unchanged?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

shouldn't the n=1 be n=2 at the highlighted part? as it was differentiated twice?

[image]

Comment: There's no differentiation going on between those two expressions.

Comment: They simplified the expression by canceling factorial terms. Look after the $=$ sign that a factor $(2n)$ has disappeared from the numerator. After this , see Pat's answer

Comment: Your question is why does it not go to $n=2$. The answer is that a term only disappears when it is $x^0$. The expression for $f(x)$ has such a term (when $n=0$), but the expression for $f'(x)$ does not, since the smallest term (when $n=1$) has an $x^1$.

Comment: @ Dr Xorile In another word, the change of the index all depends on if any of the terms have been cancelled?

Comment: @ Dr Xorile In another word, the change of the index all depends on if any of the terms have been cancelled? for example, if I were to find $f(x)'''$, then another first turn would drop, because it is 1. right? so if it is $f(x)^{n} $and n is even, then there is no need to change n, if it is odd,n would need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when we differentiate a power series, we lose a term off the front because it's constant.  But in this case, the powers are all even.  Since there is no $x^1$ term in $f(x)$, there is no constant term in $f'(x)$.  We're counting by $2$'s here, so only every other differentiation erases a term.

Comment: @ B Goddard  In another word, the change of the index all depends on if any of the terms have been cancelled? for example, if I were to find $f(x)'''$, then another first turn would drop, because it is 1. right? so if it is $f(x)^{n} $and n is even, then there is no need to change n, if it is odd,n would need to change?

Comment: @Tmm  Yes.  Because the index is really $2n$.

Answer (score 1):

They didn't do anything with that summation. All they did was cancel out the inter-term.  In the next part of the equation, that's when they changed the indices for the summation.

Answer (score 0):

No this is correct.
The $(2n)(2n-1)$ in the numerator simplifies the $(2n)!$ in the denominator, and the exponent is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

${(2n)(2n-1)\over (2n)!}={1\over (2(n-1))!}$ . . .